# How to shutdown postgres through psql?

Tags: postgresql, psql, shutdown

The recommended way to shutdown `postgres` is to send a signal representing the different shutdown modes (fast, smart, immediate) or using init managers (`initd`, `systemd`, etc.) or their equivalent on non-Linux OS. In a containerized environment it's sometimes more convenient to gain access through `psql` than `docker exec` and thus more convenient to stop the server through `psql`. Is there a way to do that (given that the privileges have been granted)?

The solution can be hacky since this will mostly be used to stop a `postgres` to delete a PostgreSQL data directory in a development environment.

Comment: The level of access needed to delete the data directory should be the same level of access needed to shut it down correctly.  Why not just do that?

Answer (score 5):

The [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/server-shutdown.html) tells you to send a signal to the master `postgres` process, or to let `pg_ctl` do this.

In SQL, you can extract the PID of the master process from `pg_read_file('postmaster.pid')`, but `pg_cancel_backend()` does not accept this PID.

However, you should be able to execute these commands with COPY (depending on what rights the postgres OS user has):

```
COPY (SELECT 1) TO PROGRAM 'kill -INT `head -1 /usr/local/pgsql/data/postmaster.pid`';
```

```
COPY (SELECT 1) TO PROGRAM 'pg_ctl -D /usr/local/pgsql/data stop';
```

Comment: thanks, the following command worked for me `psql -c "COPY (SELECT 1) TO PROGRAM 'pg_ctl stop -m smart --no-wait';"`
This allows the transaction/query to finish without waiting for the stop and the database to stop when no more connections are active.